# How to transfer 2D array from Kotlin to C++

Tags: android, c++, arrays, kotlin

So, kotlin supports native c++, and I have a function on c++. Problem is, it requires 2D array (aka array of arrays) containing integers and this array should be changed. How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to pass 2d int array from kotlin to C/C++. You need to pass your array as object array. You can then convert your object array in JNI environment to int array and process it.

Here is the kotlin code:

```
external fun pass2DIntArray(array: Array<IntArray>)
```

Here is the c code:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_NativeLibrary_pass2DIntArray(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobjectArray array) {
    // Get the size of the 2D array
    jint rows = env->GetArrayLength(array);
    jint cols = env->GetArrayLength(static_cast<jarray>(env->GetObjectArrayElement(array, 0)));

    // Access the elements of the 2D array
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        jintArray row = (jintArray) env->GetObjectArrayElement(array, i);
        jint *data = env->GetIntArrayElements(row, nullptr);

        // Process the data as needed (e.g., print it)
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf("%d ", data[j]);
        }

        // Release the elements
        env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(row, data, 0);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I hope you know how to load native library.